# What is the source for Yosef's garment being a "coat of many colors"?

Tags: clothing, translation, yosef

What is the source for Yosef's coat being a "coat of many colors"? Is there a particular commentator that translates פַּסִּים as colorful?

> Genesis 37:3
>
> וְיִשְׂרָאֵ֗ל אָהַ֤ב אֶת־יוֹסֵף֙ מִכׇּל־בָּנָ֔יו כִּֽי־בֶן־זְקֻנִ֥ים
> ה֖וּא ל֑וֹ וְעָ֥שָׂה ל֖וֹ כְּתֹ֥נֶת פַּסִּֽים׃
> Now Israel loved Joseph best of all his sons, for he was the child of his old age; and he had
> made him an ornamented tunic

https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.37.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: Good discussion here - https://jewishaction.com/religion/jewish-thought/whats-truth-josephs-amazing-technicolor-dreamcoat/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Jewish Action](https://jewishaction.com/religion/jewish-thought/whats-truth-josephs-amazing-technicolor-dreamcoat/) article mentioned by @dov (thank you) contains the following paragraph:

> The earliest mention of the ketonet passim being a variegated garment
> dates back to the third-century bce Greek Septuagint, which translates
> it as χιτῶνα ποικίλον (poikilos)—a cloak of various colors. (In II
> Samuel it translates the same word differently: karpótos.) Following
> the Septuagint, the fourth-century Latin Vulgate translates ketonet
> passim as “tunicam polymitam”—a tunic woven with many threads, usually
> taken to mean different colored threads. The early seventeenth-century
> English King James Bible calls it a “coat of many colours.” Possibly
> based on this, the once standard Jewish English translation, the 1917
> Jewish Publication Society (JPS) Tanakh, calls it “a coat of many
> colors.” Some traditional commentaries adopted this interpretation.
> The influential eleventh-century Hebrew grammarian Jonah ibn Janach
> (Sefer HaShorashim, entry “pas” [p. 405]) assumes “passim” is the
> plural of “pas,” and based on Daniel and the Targum to Kings, “pas” is
> a handbreadth; thus, the ketonet passim was a silk garment in which
> each handspan was a different color. Radak (1160-1235; Provence),
> based on Daniel, derives that the garment was made of stripes of
> various colors. Ralbag (II Samuel 13:18) says that each handspan of
> the garment was a different color, and it included many colors.

So the well-known commentators who subscribe to the colours idea are the Radak and the Ralbag.